# C# Web service - Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority 'noded1.test.webservices.amadeus.com'

Tags: c#, web-services, amadeus

I'm currently working on a console app which is using some Amadeus webservices. When I'm running the application locally, everything works without any problem. However, I'm getting the following error message when I'm trying to use it on a virtual machine (Windows Server 2003) using remote desktop connection :

> Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel
>   with authority 'noded1.test.webservices.amadeus.com'.

I don't really see any blocking issue so I can't really figure out where the problem is.

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Can you load the url via a browser on the VM

Answer (score 0):

A http GET to 'noded1.test.webservices.amadeus.com' returns a Http 500 Internal server error.

https://webservices.amadeus.com/ uses a VeriSign certificate. Try accessing this url from your virtual machine.

- Is there any reason why your virtual machine would not trust VeriSign?
- Is the time set correctly on the virtual machine?